# IndexOutOfBoundsException - RecyclerView into RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview

So after a long time, I've finally found a way to display an `Horizontal RecyclerView` into another `RecyclerView`.

I followed this tutorial: http://mithunkumarc.blogspot.com/2016/09/nested-recyclerview-or-inner-recycler.html

To put some context, I am fetching some `JSON` data, into an object called "Application". I have three different fragments. These fragments are displaying `RecyclerView` with the previous data.

Into these applications, I have for each one a list of photos. So I followed the mentionned tutorial to display these photos into another `RecyclerView` (Sounds a lot like `Nested RecyclerView`)

But when I launch my first `fragment`, I encounter the following error:

> java
>
> 2019-08-28 10:11:40.120 6403-6403/com.example.applicationpro
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.applicationpro, PID: 6403
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
>           at com.example.applicationpro.adapter.PhotoAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PhotoAdapter.java:38)
>           at com.example.applicationpro.adapter.PhotoAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PhotoAdapter.java:17)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1279)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:659)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)
>           at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1274)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
>           at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:315)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:260)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9119)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1583)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
>   2019-08-28 10:11:40.121 6403-6403/com.example.applicationpro
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20132)

Parent adapter (onBindViewHolder & onCreateViewHolder methods)

```java
        // PHOTO PART
        if (mApplication.getmListOfViews() != null) {
            mListOfPhotos.addAll(mApplication.getmListOfViews());
            @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        mApplicationItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_application, parent, false);
        mContext = parent.getContext();

        return new ViewHolder(mApplicationItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Application mApplication = mListOfApplications.get(position);

        holder.mApplicationCV.setTag(position);

        int mCreditUsed = mApplication.getmDelay().getmCost();

        holder.mApplicationBrandNameTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.request, mApplication.getmApplicationArticle().getmBrand().getmName()));
        holder.mApplicationStartDateTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.creationDate, mDateInterface.convertDateToString(mApplication.getmCreationDate())));

        switch (mCreditUsed) {
            case 8:
                holder.mApplicationDelayTV.setText(R.string.consEightCredit);
                break;
            case 12:
                holder.mApplicationDelayTV.setText(R.string.consTwelveCredit);
                break;
            case 14:
                holder.mApplicationDelayTV.setText(R.string.consFourteenCredit);
                break;
            case 26:
                holder.mApplicationDelayTV.setText(R.string.consTwentySixCredit);
                break;
            case 30:
                holder.mApplicationDelayTV.setText(R.string.consThirtyCredit);
                break;
            case 42:
                holder.mApplicationDelayTV.setText(R.string.consFortyTwoCredit);
                break;
            default:
                holder.mApplicationDelayTV.setText(R.string.consNoDelayFound);
                break;
        }

        holder.mApplicationEstimationTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.estimationDate, mDateInterface.convertDateToString(mApplication.getmDelay().getmDateEstimation())));

        // SPECIMEN PART
        if (mApplication.getmCertificate() != null) {
            if (!mApplication.getmCertificate().equals("")) {

                if (mApplication.getmStatus().equals("Authentique")) {
                    holder.mApplicationSpecimenIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.specimen_valid);
                    holder.mApplicationSpecimenIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (mApplication.getmStatus().equals("Non conforme")) {
                    holder.mApplicationSpecimenIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.specimen_not_valid);
                    holder.mApplicationSpecimenIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


                holder.mApplicationSpecimenIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent mBrowserIntent = new Intent();
                        mBrowserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        mBrowserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mListOfApplications.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmCertificate()));
                        mActivity.startActivity(mBrowserIntent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // PHOTO PART
        if (mApplication.getmListOfViews() != null) {
            mListOfPhotos.addAll(mApplication.getmListOfViews());
        }

        LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this.mActivity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        holder.mApplicationPhotosRV.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayout);
        holder.mApplicationPhotosRV.setHasFixedSize(true);

        PhotoAdapter mPhotoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(this.mActivity, mListOfApplications, mListOfPhotos);
        holder.mApplicationPhotosRV.setAdapter(mPhotoAdapter);


        if (mApplication.getmInformations() == null || mApplication.getmInformations().isEmpty()) {
            if (mApplication.getmStatus().equals("Archivé ou annulé") || mApplication.getmStatus().equals("Ne se prononce pas")) {
                holder.mApplicationInfoLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mApplicationInfosTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.status, mApplication.getmStatus()));
            }
        } else {
            holder.mApplicationInfoLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (mApplication.getmStatus().equals("Archivé ou annulé") || mApplication.getmStatus().equals("Ne se prononce pas")) {
                holder.mApplicationInfosTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.informations, mApplication.getmInformations(), mApplication.getmStatus()));
            } else {
                holder.mApplicationInfosTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.informations, mApplication.getmInformations(), null));
            }
        }

        holder.mApplicationIDTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.ID, mApplication.getmIDApplication()));
        holder.mApplicationReferenceTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.reference, mApplication.getmReference()));
    }
```

Child Adapter (also onCreateViewHolder & onBindViewHolder)

```java
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PhotoAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mPhotoItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_application_photo, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(mPhotoItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Application mApplication = mListOfApplications.get(position);

        if (mApplication != null) {
            if (!mApplication.getmListOfViews().isEmpty()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mApplication.getmListOfViews().size(); i++) {
                    String mPath = mApplication.getmListOfViews().get(i)
                            .replaceAll("\\[", "")
                            .replaceAll("\"", "")
                            .replaceAll("\\]", "");
                    mApplication.getmListOfViews().set(i, mPath);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < mApplication.getmListOfViews().size(); j++) {

                    ImageView mImageView = holder.mPhotoIV;
                    int width = mImageView.getLayoutParams().width;
                    int height = mImageView.getLayoutParams().height;
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(mApplication.getmListOfViews().get(j)).resize(width, height)
                            .error(R.drawable.ic_no_photo_foreground).into(mImageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {

                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

EDIT: Method getItemCount from PhotoAdapter

```java
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListOfPhotos.size();
    }
```

I have debugged my application, `mListOfApplications` and `mListOfPhotos` have the right and expected data.

What am I missing :)?

Comment: post your getItemCount() method

Comment: The issue is on PhotoAdapter.onBindViewHolder

Comment: In your onBindViewHolder you are using mListOfApplications.get(position); for both. It is wrong. Each adapter has to use its arraylist.

Comment: @GhostCat It wasn't a duplicate post. The issue was different :)